# With two pending intents, getLongExtra() returns the first intent extra value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have two `PendingIntent` s. Each one has one `Intent` which has an `putExtra()` value. First `PendingIntent` is used first. When I use the second `PendingIntent`, it returns the value of the first `Intent`. Each `Intent` has a unique key and each `PendingIntent` has unique request code. But still I have the problem.

First pending Intent:

```
Intent roshanIntent = new Intent(sendSMS).putExtra("Roshan", System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent sendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), roshanIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Second pending Intent:

```
Intent mtnIntent = new Intent(sendSMS).putExtra("MTN", System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent sendPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), mtnIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

When I get the `getLongExtra()` of the `mtnIntent`, it returns the `roshanIntent` values.

**Edit:**

I also tried to setAction() to Intent, but it returns zero.

```
mtnIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: if `requestCode`s are different (as you say) it cannot happen, double check `requestCode`s

Comment: I have got requestCode s System.currentTimeMillis(). They are unique, aren't they?

Comment: as i said just check it, why dont you use `Log.d` to show them?

Comment: Please show more of your code. What device are you testing on? Have you added logging to see if the request codes are really unique. The description of your problem makes no sense. There is something else going on.